# feather edges in raster images with GDAL

Tags: gis, gdal, qgis, osgeo

Can someone tell me how to feather the edges of an image using `gdal`?
I have been under the impression that the `-cblend` switch would do it but maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

This is what I've tried:

`gdalwarp -t_srs ESPG:4326 -multi -cblend 200 -of GTiff input.jp2 test.tiff`

I don't mind doing this from within QGIS or just in the OSGeo4W command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

This response is to a very old post, but for the sake of those searching for an answer to this issue, it might be good to offer a solution.

To use `-cblend` you need to have a `-cutline` associated with the command. `-cblend` creates the blend area where a cutline is applied.

`gdalwarp -t_srs ESPG:4326 -multi -cutline '/cutlineshape.shp' -cblend 200 -of GTiff input.jp2 test.tiff`